# Timer to start from the entered value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in which I have  Field named 'Start Time' and 'Stop time'.Data in start time field  is entered by user and stop field is in disabled mode initially. I want to enable the stop field after the 3 hrs of the entered value in start time.  is it possible by java script/php/html.Which is the best way to achieve it.My java code is

```
function timedOut() {
    alert("First Process Completed");
}

// set a timer
setTimeout( timedOut , 600000 );
```

I am calling this java function on the click on the submit button.Can i  do it automatically  after one hour of enterd value in start filed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: If you tried something and difficult in getting solution, post your code here with the error you got.

Comment: @mplungjan i have updated my efforts

Comment: JAVA is not the same as JavScript. Please have a look around first. Your attempt is not very useful. You need something like 
`function timedOut() {
    document.getElementById("stopField").disabled=false;
}
setTimeout( timedOut , new Date(document.getElementById("startfield").value()).getTime() - new Date().getTime() +(3*60*60*1000))`

Answer (score -1):

Use Javascript/sessionStorage or javascript/localStorage on client side. If u you need to record the time on the server then send the start-time to php